# How to move the player to a specific point in a 2D Unity Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have something like this in my game:

```
Vector2 screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
if (screenPosition.y > Screen.height || screenPosition.y < 0)
{

}
```

Which finds if the player is not in the window.
I want it to move the player to a specific coordinate.
So what would teleport the player to those coordinates?

Comment: When you say a specific coordinate, what do you mean? a Vector3 in the world? a Vector2 on the screen? something relative to the player or camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code

```
Vector2 screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
float targetX = 100; // replace it with your value
float targetY = 100; // replace it with your value
if (screenPosition.y > Screen.height || screenPosition.y < 0)
{
     transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(targetX, targetY, camera.nearClipPlane));
}
```

Comment: It's generally suggested that you accompany your answer with some form of explanation.